# Adding password to single slide in powerpoint

Tags: powerpoint

As we already have the feature of adding password to ppt file now I want to add password to particular slide in powerpoint. This is because i added a chart in the presentation and i want the chart to be visible only for some users. How can i do this

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  Instead, you could link from your main presentation to another password-protected presentation that contains only the slide with the chart.